# Hello How can I update the value of a label with the value i get from a textbox?

Tags: vb.net

The code I use is the following:

```
' (is on top of the listing directly after Public class form1)
Dim Score as Integer 
...
Score=Val(Txtbox5.text) "Txtbox5 is control where I put in the value."
Lbl2.text=score  "Lbl2 is the label where the score must display."
Txtbox5.text=""  "Makes the Textbox empty."
```

Then the problem occurs: when I enter a new value in Txtbox5.text the I want this value update
the value in the label with the value that is already in the label by the score.
The code I use therefor is Lbl2.text=score +score but whats happend is the score in the label is double???
So what I want is: when I have a value in the label say 2 and I insert a new value in the textbox
say 3 then I want to see in the label a value of 5.
But I have tried everything but nothing works
Is there somebody who can help me with this problem??

Comment: Did you try with _Score += Val(Txtbox5.text)_ and then set the label to show the new Score value

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work see my code below.

Comment: Private Sub TxtBox5_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TxtBox5.KeyDown

        Score = Val(TxtBox5.Text)
        Lbl2.Text = Score
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            TxtBox5.Text = ""

        End If
        Lbl2.Text = Convert.ToInt32(Lbl2.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(TxtBox5.Text)

    End Sub

Comment: Steve Thanks very much your solution is working---many thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried everything but nothing works

That's not strictly true..

```
Lbl2.Text = (Convert.ToInt32("0"&Lbl2.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(Txtbox5.Text)).ToString()
```

ps;
Your life would be a lot simpler if you used a couple of numericupdown controls, one readonly and no border etc to look like a label. Then life would be like:

```
resultNumericUpDown.Value += inputNumericUpDown.Value
```

Whenever you're asking the user for numbers, using a NUD saves a lot of headaches

Comment: Sorry but this is not working I get a System.Format Exeption??

Comment: You have put a number in both the label and the textbox, right? Set the label to "0" initially, and the textbox to eg "5"

Comment: I added a bit of a workaround for if your label is blank to start with

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to sum the current value of the TextBox5 to the Score variable and then update the label

This could be simply resolved without any thinking with

```
Score += Val(Textbox5.Text)
Lbl2.text=Score  
Txtbox5.Text=""
```

But you could meet some problems because in your  textbox the user can type anything, not just a number. In that context the Val function from the Microsoft.VisualBasic compatibility assemble doesn't tell you anything, simply converts the non numeric string to zero. This could be acceptable or not depending on your requirements. If you want to have a message for your user when the input is not good you could write

```
Dim currentInput as Integer
if Not Int32.TryParse(Txtbox5.Text, currentInput) Then
    MessageBox.Show("You should input a numeric value!")
Else
    Score = Score + currentInput
    Lbl2.text=Score  
    Txtbox5.Text=""
End If
```